# Removing changes from one file in a commit

Tags: git, github, commit

I have a private repo with a single commit on Github -- specifically for a Rails project. My schema file was changed along with migrations, and a fellow dev wants me to remove the schema changes from the commit (and the private repo). I thought I had it figured out but it doesn't seem to be sticking, what am I doing wrong?

```
git reset 'HEAD^1' db/schema.rb
git commit --amend -v
git push origin <branch-name> -f
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you didn't stage the changes made to `db/schema.rb` after doing the reset and before doing the commit.  So after you do `git reset 'HEAD^1' db/schema.rb`, stage the file with `git add db/schema.rb`, then do the commit.

Alternatively, you can reset the file to the previous state and keep it staged in the index by using `git reset --soft head^` instead of `git reset head^`.  The latter uses the `--mixed` flag by default, which will not stage the changed state, while the former will.

You can read more about the `git reset` flags [in the documentation](http://jk.gs/git-reset.html):

> ```
> --soft
> ```
>
> Does not touch the index file nor the working tree at all (but resets 
>   the head to , just like all modes do). This leaves all
>   your changed files "Changes to be committed", as git status would put
>   it.
>
> ```
> --mixed
> ```
>
> Resets the index but not the working tree (i.e., the changed files are 
>   preserved but not marked for commit) and reports what has not been
>   updated. This is the default action.

Comment: I ended up using `git checkout 'HEAD^' db/schema.rb`, but yes! I did need to add the file. Not sure how I missed that. Thanks!